# What is a good class design for node-connection situation?

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures

I want to design a map like in traveling salesman problem.
There are a number of nodes, some connected to another.
One node can be connected to many other nodes.

I have designed some, which one is better ? Or maybe there are another better design ?
1.)

```
class Node {
    private int ID;
    private int position-x;
    private int position-y;
}
class Connection {
    private int ID;
    private Node first;
    private Node second;
    public void ConnectTwoNodes( Node a, Node b ) { ... }
}
```

2.)

```
class Node {
    private int ID;
    private int position-x;
    private int position-y;
    private ArrayList<Node> anotherNodes; // array of connected nodes
    public void ConnectTo( Node another ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: What you are really asking is [how to represent a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations). The answer is "it totally depends on what you are going to do with it".

Comment: Depends on the language also, different languages may provide unique conveniences.

Comment: It's not really an OOP question but a data structure and algorithm question.

Comment: @Jon, please describe or give examples on what you mean by _"it totally depends on what you are going to do with it"_. Please, I'm a newbie programmer.

Comment: @uchuugaka, thanks, I've added those tags

Comment: @topher: See the table at the link I offered? It has a table of operations vs their [algorithmic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) (or memory footprint) for each manner of representing the graph. You supposedly know which operations and in what kind of mix you will be performing on the graph; therefore you should choose the representation which offers the best (lowest) cost for those operations. I realize that this is rather abstract, but if you want to make an informed decision that is what you need to do.

Comment: @Jon, thank you for your help, now I have some clarity. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language seems to be C++.
Your solution 1. has the following problems:

- class Connection seems to "aggregate" the Nodes. It should rather be an association in OOspeak (a pointer to a Node to make it understandable to mere mortals)
- a Connection object has absolutely no reason to exist, unless it connects 2 Nodes. So the function of ConnectTwoNodes belongs in a constructor. In other words rename it to Connection.

In your second solution it also seems that a Node contains the other Nodes. But in reality they exist independently. Again, you need associations, or pointers to other Nodes.

I actually prefer the 1. approach. Or a non-OO solution with a matrix, with "from" Nodes on one axle and "to" Nodes on the other. It also allows you to handle cases when it's possible to get from New York to Paris, Texas but not vice versa, because there are no more flights in the afternoon. In other words a directional graph.

Comment: The language is C#, not that it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier on my question that I will use Java language. Looks like Java doesn't have pointers, so I think, by writing `Node a;`, Java handles it as a pointer. CMIIW